# repeat action to more data entry for excel userform

Tags: excel, vba

As a non-professional but research for accelerate data entry in excel, I've designed an Excel userform with 'split row and columns' for each 'Actors' and 'Paxs' textboxes. With initial input, the entry was fine but when repeat, the information overwritten the recent ones. I've no knowledge to adjust such overwriting. Do I miss something there? advise,please.

```
Private Sub cmdIn_Click()

Dim RowCnt As Long
Dim Actors As Variant
Dim ColNum1 As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim Paxs As Variant
Dim ColNum2 As Variant
Dim k As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ActPaxs")

RowCnt = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

RowCnt = 2
Actors = Split(Me.TxtActors.Value, vbCrLf)
    For Each r In Actors
        j = 1
        ColNum1 = Split(r, ", ")
    For Each c In ColNum1
        ws.Cells(RowCnt, j).Value = c
      j = j + 1
    Next c
      RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
  Next r

RowCnt = 2
Paxs = Split(Me.TxtPaxs.Value, vbCrLf)
    For Each p In Paxs
        k = 4
        ColNum2 = Split(p, ", ")
    For Each q In ColNum2
        ws.Cells(RowCnt, k).Value = q
      k = k + 1
    Next q
        RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
  Next p


TxtActors.Text = ""
TxtPaxs.Text = ""

End Sub
```

How to repeat same code to add more data and not overwrite the existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

```
RowCnt = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

RowCnt = 2
```

delete the second instance which hard codes to row 2, the first instance detects the last used row and offsets by 1

Edit: you have another instance of RowCnt = 2 further down in the code, delete that too.

Comment: I tested already. The first 'Split' (of Actors) worked fine but the second 'Split' (of Paxs) returned the output to the "D4" as I want it to "D2" (Row#1 is header). I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @SamAng where the second ‘RowCnt = 2’ was put ‘RowCnt = RowCnt-2’